# bourbon mixins not working with Code Kit 3

Tags: sass, bourbon, codekit

I am using bourbon and neat for the first time after switching over from compass. My set up is as follows:

Importing bourbon and neat at the top of my main SASS file like so:

```
 @import "bourbon";
 @import "neat";
```

Installed using CodeKit 3

All of my neat mixins work great. But any bourbon mixins fail. For example this is the error I get with the linear-gradient mixin

```
   Libsass: Error: no mixin named linear-gradient

   Backtrace:
    /dev/assets/design/sass/main.scss:117
    on line 117 of /dev/assets/design/sass/main.scss
    @include linear-gradient(#1e5799, #2989d8);
```

I thought that neat needed bourbon to work. So I can't understand why my mixins don't work. Assuming I am making a newbie mistake. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Importing bourbon is more like @import "bourbon/bourbon". First bourbon is the directory, the 2nds bourbon is the bourbon.scss file (or bourbon.sass file, whichever you are using)

Comment: I tried that, no luck. I also tried reinstalling the bourbon files in the root directory, in the main SASS directory and in a separate folder. Each time regardless of the path and where the files are I get the same error

Answer (score 0):

What Brad said is pretty much right, except, depending on how you installed it you might find the path is different.

I was able to get it working with the following (my sass is 2 folders below the project root btw).

```
@import "../../bower_components/bourbon/app/assets/stylesheets/bourbon";
```

Also, I installed from within codekit package library

[close up of codekit package search input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LcMPu.png)

[codekit search results package list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqBpq.png)

You click the arrow on the far right next to the package you want to install.

Hope that helps.